# Unlock Jenkins 2 without UI

Tags: curl, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to unlock Jenkins 2 using the curl command in the VM where Jenkins Server is installed. I have the following:

```
curl 'admin:a84b61b7f2704b18ada3cbd32c3ad39e@127.0.0.1:8080/j_acegi_security_check -X POST -d {"from":"","j_username":"admin","j_password":"a84b61b7f2704b18ada3cbd32c3ad39e","Jenkins-Crumb":"90b3cf29bdf16c9790227a3f8a8674bf"}'
```

The secrets are showing but I have a bash variable for each one. When I execute the curl command I always have a 302 status code.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Why is a 302 status code bad? That would suggest that you logged-in successfully and are being redirected to the home page. Otherwise it would be a 401, or maybe 403.

Comment: Are you the Jenkins administrator as well? You're aware of the  [`jenkins.install.runSetupWizard`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Features+controlled+by+system+properties) property?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm trying to configure Jenkins with bash scripts due to I need to prepare it without UI configuration as I can. I know the runSetupWizard over the /etc/default and jenkins file, but I need to secure Jenkins since bash scripts.

Comment: If I execute the request using DHCP or another API Client, it works; but I don't know if I need a special header or something like that. Right now, my curl is:

Comment: curl -i -X POST \
-H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" \
-H "Accept:*/*" \
-d "from=/" \
-d "j_username=admin" \
-d "j_password=591e0cbfc6f4488291eac4b72c56772a" \
-d "Jenkins-Crumb=817cfa1009f8e8b8db579a8b969e79bb" \
-d "json={ \"from\": \"/\",   \"j_username\": \"admin\",   \"j_password\": \"591e0cbfc6f4488291eac4b72c56772a\",   \"Jenkins-Crumb\": \"817cfa1009f8e8b8db579a8b969e79bb\"  }" \
'http://1270.0.1:8080/j_acegi_security_check'